# VC dimension of finite unions of one-sided intervals

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory, vc-dimension

What is the VC dimension of $k$ finite unions of one-sided intervals:

If we take 3 one-sided intervals like $(-\infty, a_1] $, $(-\infty, a_2] $ and $(-\infty, a_3] $, I think union of these intervals can shatter $4
$ points as below, assuming that $a_1>a_2>a_3>a_4$:

- Point $p_1$ at interval $(-\infty, a_1]$
- Point $p_2$ at interval $[a_1, a_2]$
- Point $p_3$ at interval $[a_2,a_3]$
- Point $p_4$ at interval $(-\infty, a_3]$

For $k$ finite unions I think answer is $k+1$, am I right?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "$k$ finite unions of one-sided intervals"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I mean union of $(-\infty, a1] U (-\infty, a2] U (-\infty, a3] $

Comment: This union is equal to $(-\infty, \max(a_1,a_2,a_3))$, that is, to a single interval.

Comment: Is $[a1,+\infty)$ also a one-sided interval? Can you copy and past **the full original problem statement** or provide an accessible link? As implied by Yuval Filmus, it is not easy to comprehend your paraphrase of the problem. By the way, the VC dimension of the subsets of the real line
formed by the union of $k$ intervals is $2k$.

Answer (score 1):

Finite unions of one-sided intervals can shatter only 2 points, because as said by @YuvalFilmus in comments the union of Finite unions is a single one-sided interval, and a single one-sided interval can shatter only 2 points.

Comment: It seems more likely that you misunderstood the definition of one-sided interval.